# Core data: Serious application error.

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, core-data

Hi I am new to core data and I am trying to update my tableview once the data is saved in core data. I am using the delegates of core data for doing this.

My scenario is:

1. I fetch the contact list of user, save it in core data and then update the tableview in section 1 with name Invite Contacts, my section 0 is fixed for search bar.
2. Once I got the list of contact I find the existing contacts who are using my app and then I do the following:

   Add a new section 1 with name Existing Contacts and move the Invite Contacts to section 2.

   Move the cells from Invite Contacts to Existing Contacts.

I got the following error in section update :
CoreData: error: Serious application error.

> An exception was caught from the delegate of
>   NSFetchedResultsController during a call to
>   -controllerDidChangeContent:.  attempt to insert row 32 into section 2, but there are only 32 rows in section 2 after the update with
>   userInfo (null)

I have 47 contacts and 15 existing contacts. So in second update I move 15 cells from Invite Contacts to Existing Contacts. And the above error occurs at endupdates of UITableView.

I am using the following delegates of Core data:

> - (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id )sectionInfo
>     atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex
>     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
> - (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
>     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
>     newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath

Comment: How many rows have you defined for the section? I believe the indexing for table rows starts at 0.

Comment: How can we help without seeing your code?

Comment: Couple of comments... From the limited context of the question you've got a number of questions that need to be answered... slow down and take smaller steps... There are a number of similar questions on this and other forums that would help you. Do more research on `NSFetchedResultsController` and its delegates. Read the `UITableView` class reference documentation on **Inserting, Deleting, and Moving Rows and Sections** and using `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` and the insert and delete rows/sections methods.